# Php json_encode returning different values on 2 different servers for same object

Tags: php, arrays, json, ubuntu, nginx

I have 2 servers, each running the same application, and I have a function returning a json response.

When using `print_r($object)` I get this on both servers:

```
Array
(
    [stats] => Array
        (
            [6871] => 200
        )

    [answers] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7171
        )

)
```

When I use `json_encode($object);` I get this:

For server A:

```
{"stats":{"6871":200},"answers":["7171"]}
```

For server B:

```
{"stats":{"6871":200},"answers":[7171]}
```

So the one server is encoding the integer value of `answers` as a string.

The servers are running:

- ubuntu

  - server A: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
  - server B: Ubuntu 13.10
- nginx

  - server A: nginx/1.6.2
  - server B: nginx/1.5.12
- php-fpm

  - server A: PHP 5.5.9
  - server B PHP 5.5.3

Both nginx.conf files are identical. I can't seem to figure out where the issue is and I've been sitting at this for hours, does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Do a `var_dump` to more clearly show the types in the input.  `print_r` likes to hide that info from you.  It's possible your input is different on the two machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `print_r()` function does not accurately represent data types:

```
<?php

$string_values = array(
    'stats' => array (
        6871 => '200'
    ),
);

$numeric_values = array(
    'stats' => array (
        6871 => 200,
    ),
);


print_r($string_values);
print_r($numeric_values);
```

... will print the same output twice:

```
Array
(
    [stats] => Array
        (
            [6871] => 200
        )

)
Array
(
    [stats] => Array
        (
            [6871] => 200
        )

)
```

You'd better switch to `var_dump()`:

```
var_dump($string_values, $numeric_values);
```

```
array(1) {
  ["stats"]=>
  array(1) {
    [6871]=>
    string(3) "200"
  }
}
array(1) {
  ["stats"]=>
  array(1) {
    [6871]=>
    int(200)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, still no idea WHY the 2 servers are returning different data types, but your suggestion helped me realize where the string value was being inserted and i used intval() to always force it so the 2 servers are consistent